# Insert multiple elements into a specific indexes

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to solve the following problem in one line. I looked at the itertools docs to find a specific function for this but no luck. Say
a = [1, 2, 3,4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

I want to insert the elements of b into a, but each element into a specific index. So

```
insert_function(a, b, keys=[0,1, 2, 3])
```

should return

```
[5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]
```

Comment: Mmm `6` is not at index `2` is at index `3`

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the indexes a bit. I edited it but I think what I tried to say is still clear though

Comment: What is the `keys` parameter for?

Comment: @DanielHao it doesn't matter

Comment: @DaniMesejo It shows the indexes where the new elements should be inserted into

Comment: Now `6` is not at index `1`, but at index `2`...

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
def insert_function(la, lb, keys=None):
    ii = [i + k for i, k in enumerate(keys)]
    i, j = 0, 0

    ret = []
    for r in range(len(la) + len(lb)):
        if r in ii:
            ret.append(lb[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            ret.append(la[i])
            i += 1
    return ret


res = insert_function(a, b, keys=[0, 1, 2, 3])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]
```

Or as an alternative use this one-liner list comprehension with `O(n + m)` time complexity:

```
def insert_function(la, lb, keys=None):
    ii = set(i + k for i, k in enumerate(keys))
    it_a, it_b = iter(a), iter(b)
    return [next(it_a) if r not in ii else next(it_b) for r in range(len(la) + len(lb))]


res = insert_function(a, b, keys=[0, 1, 2, 3])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you insert elements you shift the subsequent indices. That can be prevented by inserting  *from right to left*:

```py
def insert_function(a, b, keys):
    # copy so original list is left intact
    a = a.copy()
    
    # sort the keys in reverse
    for k,v in sorted(zip(keys, b), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True):
        a.insert(k, v)

    return a

# returns [5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]
print(insert_function(a, b, [0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
def insert_function(a, b, keys):
    assert len(b) == len(keys)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        a.insert(keys[i], b[i])
```

Comment: To be clear, this will edit list a in place, and will return None.